# Unknown title 60's sci fi book possibility started with a G or the word star

Tags: story-identification, hard-sci-fi

1. I remember finding this book in my dad's old college collection so possibly publish in the 50-60's
2. Cover had a white or silver tower on a background of a lot of orange or an explosion
3. A boy or man laying on his stomach on a silver metal plate that looked to be zooming from the tower.
4. a winged bat/pterodactyl like creature with claws flying above the man
5. I remember a young man in a rookery of sorts raising said winged things. The man had an amulet. Something happens where the man escapes to a tower the amulet reacts to the tower and he and one of the winged creatures he was caring for
   were transported far away

Comment: You can accept an answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Answer (score 18):

I remember seeing a cover on a paperback book by Andre Norton with a boy riding a device like a surfboard flying in the air.  I don't remember if there was a tower or a "terror dactyl" on the cover.

If my memory is correct I probably saw the cover in the 1960s so a book or edition published after 1970 would probably not be the one I remember.

Unfortunately Andre Norton was very prolific, so that does not limit it down very much.

But after searching at the Internet Speculative Fiction Database I found a cover which should be the one I remember, the cover of the 1963 Ace Books edition of [*Star Gate*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/531049.Star_Gate).

[image: Star Gate]

From the [plot summary on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Gate_(novel)):

> Riding his larng Cim, the four-eyed analogue of a horse, and **accompanied by his pterodactyl-like hunting mord, Vorken**, he leaves the only world he has known, following a map that his grandfather gave him. Falling in with a party of cross-breeds and a Star Lord, he helps them fight off outlaws and **follows them through a pair of luminous webs to another Gorth**. As they pass through the Star Gate **Kincar is burned by an amulet, a Tie, that he wears**. Joined by others, the group takes refuge in an abandoned keep that they find on their new world. Kincar meets a healer, Lady Asgar, who treats his burn while Lord Dillan tells him about many worlds and of travel between them. They have come to a Gorth that they had not intended to occupy, so they will have to build another Star Gate.

Comment: Well caught sir! Yes this is it. The "amulet" is called *The Tie* and is worn by a young man called *Kincar*. the pterodactyl like creatures are *mords*.

Comment: The large aerial predators (pictured) are _sa-mords_; _mords_ are smaller and domesticated, like Kincar s'Rud's companion Vorken.

Comment: Ha. I have that one too... but didn’t remember the cover. I guess my memory is biased to Vance vs Norton.   Good sleuthing!

Comment: Holy guacamole, 45 cents for a novel? I did a quick inflation calculation, and I guess that's about right calculating from 1960. It'd be about $8.66 today, but wow.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly the book I remembered. I have since found the book. It did my heart good to read it again after so much time. It had not lost it's luster! Thank you again.